# al correr la ruta la node me manda este mensaje: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Al acceder a la ruta que especifique, no se cargan los archivos que tengo en la carpeta publico, solo se cargan algunos y en la consola de nodejs me manda el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>     at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (C:\api-rest\node_modules\send\index.js:402:13)
>     at SendStream.send (C:\api-rest\node_modules\send\index.js:625:10)
>     at onstat (C:\api-rest\node_modules\send\index.js:737:10)
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>     at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (C:\api-rest\node_modules\send\index.js:402:13)
> ```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, err) => {

Noticias.find({}, (e, noticias) => {
    noticias.forEach(function (element) {
        var myStrin = '' + element.Contenido;
        myStrin = myStrin.slice(0, 100);
        element.Contenido = myStrin + '...';
    }, this);
    if (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } else if (!noticias) {
        console.log("Error, el archivo no existe")
    } else {
        res.render('index', { noticias, title: "ICMA", uno: "select", dos: "", tres: "", cuatro: "", cinco: "" })
    }
   }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El error hace referencia a que se está intentando responder dos veces a la petición http.

Puedes subir el código implementado en esta función ? Noticias.find() para descartar que ahí dentro estés enviando una respuesta adicional a la que tienes en res.render().